# Using a starter kit from Github

Tags: git, github

I'm not sure how to ask this question, which is why I couldn't find the answer on Google, so please bear with me.

How do you use the starter kits on Github?

If you simply do `git clone starter-url .` then you'll end up with a local repo with `git remote show origin` pointing to that original repo.

If I fork it, and then clone this forked repo, then `show origin` is points to my repo(so that's ok). But I'm looking at React kits, and now the most popular one has about 450 forks and the second 30 (isn't that a bit low?)

So, am I doing something wrong? Is there a better way? Or any additional things to be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After cloning, you can change the remote repository using the [`git remote set-url`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote) command:

```
git remote set-url origin <new-repository-url>
```

After running this, `git push` will push to your repository, not the original.